# Parse multiple JSON objects in Android

Tags: android, json

i'm confused on how to parse this JSON.
So far this is my approach. Also please tell me the right approach for parsing JSON in Android

```
JSON:

{  
 "latitude":37.8267,
 "longitude":-122.423,
 "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
 "offset":-7,
 "currently":{  
  "time":1443322196,
  "summary":"Partly Cloudy",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "nearestStormDistance":13,
  "nearestStormBearing":77,
  "precipIntensity":0,
  "precipProbability":0,
  "temperature":63.94,
  "apparentTemperature":63.94,
  "dewPoint":55.46,
  "humidity":0.74,
  "windSpeed":8.59,
  "windBearing":277,
  "visibility":8.51,
  "cloudCover":0.44,
  "pressure":1010.39,
  "ozone":261.48
 },
  "minutely":{  
   "summary":"Partly cloudy for the hour.",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "data":[  
     {  
        "time":1443322140,
        "precipIntensity":0,
        "precipProbability":0
     },
 }
```

Now the "currently" object is being parsed but when i try to parse "minutely" object it shows no value in Logcat

Here's my code:

```
JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    JSONArray summary = new JSONArray(jsonData);

    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    String city = getLocationName(forecast.getDouble("latitude"), forecast.getDouble("longitude"));

    JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
    JSONArray hour = summary.getJSONArray("minutely");
    for (int i = 0; i < hour.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = hour.getJSONObject(i);
        String summary = jsonObject.getString("summary");
    }
    CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();
    currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    currentWeather.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    currentWeather.setTemp(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
    currentWeather.setTimezone(timezone);
    currentWeather.setLocation(city);
```

Comment: provide your complete Json that you receive.As @omolara said that not a valid json.

Comment: https://api.forecast.io/forecast/8162461ea194cb97c80209d6edf4df94/37.8267,-122.423

Comment: i'm able to parse the "daily" and "hourly" objects but not minutely.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: where you "data":[ is closed? Response is incorrect or you have to post complete response

Comment: See my answer below, parsed `minutely` successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the response from the endpoint url that you added in comments the parsing would look like this

```
JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);

double latitude = forecast.getDouble("latitude");
double longitude= forecast.getDouble("longitude");
String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");

JSONObject jsonObjCurrently= forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
//parse string, long and double objects within jsonObjCurrently accordingly

JSONObject jsonObjMinutely= forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
String summary= jsonObjMinutely.getString("summary");
String icon= jsonObjMinutely.getString("icon");
JSONArray jsonArrayMinutelyData = jsonObjMinutely.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArrayMinutelyData .length(); i++){
   JSONObject tempData = jsonArrayMinutelyData.get(i);
   long time = tempData.getLong("time");
   //parse the remaining object pairs.
}

JSONObject jsonObjHourly= forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
//similar to minutely parsing. Only has more and different data 
JSONObject jsonObjDaily= forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
//similar to hourly parsing.
JSONObject jsonObjFlags= forecast.getJSONObject("flags");
//It has 5 array and 1 string object so parse accordingly.
```

I have added the parsing logic please save the data accordingly and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You may parse the `minutely` at wrong path. see code below (tested).

```
    try {
        // jsonString from https://api.forecast.io/forecast/8162461ea194cb97c80209d6edf4df94/37.8267,-122.423
        String jsonString = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject minutely = jsonObject.getJSONObject("minutely");
        Log.d("JSON", "minutely: " + minutely);
        String summary = minutely.getString("summary");
        Log.d("JSON", "summary: " + summary);

        JSONArray datas = minutely.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < datas.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject data = datas.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("JSON", "data @ index" + i + ": " + data);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output:

```
    D/JSON    ( 1590): minutely: {"summary":"Partly cloudy for the hour.","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","data":....
    D/JSON    ( 1590): summary: Partly cloudy for the hour.
    D/JSON    ( 1590): data @ index0: {"time":1443331140,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0}
    D/JSON    ( 1590): data @ index1: {"time":1443331200,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0}
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json.
You can check your logcat for the exception thrown.
If the exception has been caught, try and print stack trace. That will help you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

i check your json again and it should be one of two cases
the first is like

```
{  
 "latitude":37.8267,
 "longitude":-122.423,
 "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
 "offset":-7,
 "currently":{  
  "time":1443322196,
  "summary":"Partly Cloudy",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "nearestStormDistance":13,
  "nearestStormBearing":77,
  "precipIntensity":0,
  "precipProbability":0,
  "temperature":63.94,
  "apparentTemperature":63.94,
  "dewPoint":55.46,
  "humidity":0.74,
  "windSpeed":8.59,
  "windBearing":277,
  "visibility":8.51,
  "cloudCover":0.44,
  "pressure":1010.39,
  "ozone":261.48
 },
  "minutely":{  
   "summary":"Partly cloudy for the hour.",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "data":[  
     {  
        "time":1443322140,
        "precipIntensity":0,
        "precipProbability":0
     },
 }
```

and the solution will be look like.

```
JSONObject minutely = forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
```

second it like

```
[
    {
        "latitude": 37.8267,
        "longitude": -122.423,
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "offset": -7,
        "currently": {
            "time": 1443322196,
            "summary": "Partly Cloudy",
            "icon": "partly-cloudy-night",
            "nearestStormDistance": 13,
            "nearestStormBearing": 77,
            "precipIntensity": 0,
            "precipProbability": 0,
            "temperature": 63.94,
            "apparentTemperature": 63.94,
            "dewPoint": 55.46,
            "humidity": 0.74,
            "windSpeed": 8.59,
            "windBearing": 277,
            "visibility": 8.51,
            "cloudCover": 0.44,
            "pressure": 1010.39,
            "ozone": 261.48
        },
        "minutely": {
            "summary": "Partly cloudy for the hour.",
            "icon": "partly-cloudy-night",
            "data": [
                {
                    "time": 1443322140,
                    "precipIntensity": 0,
                    "precipProbability": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

and solution will be that you should change your forecast object to be JsonArray.

You can test the validation of your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: So your forecast object is not JSONObject it should be JSONArray

Comment: @bappibazzi It not a JsonArray i have checked your json.

Answer (score 0):

Minutely is not JSONArray its JSONObject.
Try this:-

```
JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONObject jsonObjMinutely= forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
String summary = jsonObjMinutely.getString("summary");
```

Comment: can u post complete json response.

Answer (score 0):

Your minutely is invalid JSON..

Let's take a look at that closer:

```
"minutely":{  
  "summary":"Partly cloudy for the hour.",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "data":[  
  {  
    "time":1443322140,
    "precipIntensity":0,
    "precipProbability":0
  },
```

It doesn't have a closing bracket for both the minutely's JSONObject and data's JSONArray. Also, it has a comma where "data" array actually contains one element.

Fixing those to:

```
"minutely":{  
  "summary":"Partly cloudy for the hour.",
  "icon":"partly-cloudy-night",
  "data":[  
  {  
    "time":1443322140,
    "precipIntensity":0,
    "precipProbability":0
  } ]
}
```

Then your "minutely" object is now valid. This is first.

Then to get your "minutely"

```
...
JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONObject minutely = forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
```

Answer (score 0):

parsing json is very easy now with android studio. In android studio install plugin GSON then create model class and enter 'alt+insert' it will popup for generator then select GSONFormat and paste your json there you will get model class for your json. In activity where you get json response do this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourModelClass object = gson.fromJson(jsonResponseObject.toString(), YourModelClass.class);
```

Here you succefully parsed json. Now its time to use your model class to get data whereever you want it

Answer (score -1):

Please edit your code like below

```
JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
Double humidity = currently.getDouble("humidity");
Long time = currently.getLong("time");
String icon = currently.getString("icon");
Double precipChance = currently.getDouble("precipProbability");
Double temp = currently.getDouble("temperature");
String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
JSONObject minutely = forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
```

Have a look at below link for complete example of Json Parsing

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6cjifccbbw9nl1/JsonParsing.zip?dl=0

Comment: why have you set 
        JSONObject minutely = null;

Comment: it does not matter i declare it outside the try catch it gave me the exception  object not initialized so initialize it with null.you can declare it inside try catch.

Comment: it mean you remove the declaration from outside try catch.
So you declare it inside try catch like below
   JSONObject minutely = forecast.getJSONObject("minutely");
I was supposing you know how to declare object.